# Retrieving quotient of two SUM(col) JOIN ON different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Sorry for confusing title, didn't know how to word this.

I have a table of events, and a table of bets on those events. I'm already fetching the total amount bet on each event, but I also want to fetch the odds (aka, the quotient of the total for one team divided by the total of the other team). The participant being bet on is stored in the `horse` column of the `data_bets` table.

For instance, I want to add something like:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(data_bets.amount) WHERE data_bets.horse = data_events.challenger
    /
    SUM(data_bets.amount) WHERE data_bets.horse = data_events.contestant
AS bet_odds
```

to my existing query below:

```
SELECT *,
   SUM(data_bets.amount) AS total_pot,
   COUNT(data_bets.member) AS total_bets,
   COUNT(data_votes.member) AS total_votes,
   data_platforms.name AS platform_name, data_platforms.icon AS platform_icon
FROM data_events
   LEFT JOIN data_bets ON data_bets.event=data_events.id
   LEFT JOIN data_votes ON data_votes.content_type=2 AND data_votes.content_id=data_events.id
   LEFT JOIN data_platforms ON data_platforms.id=data_events.platform
WHERE status=1
GROUP BY data_events.id
ORDER BY total_pot DESC
```

Is this possible to do with one query? If possible, I'd prefer to fetch both `challenger_odds` and `contestant_odds`, like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(data_bets.amount) WHERE data_bets.horse = data_events.challenger
    /
    SUM(data_bets.amount) WHERE data_bets.horse = data_events.contestant
AS challenger_odds, 
    SUM(data_bets.amount) WHERE data_bets.horse = data_events.contestant
    /
    SUM(data_bets.amount) WHERE data_bets.horse = data_events.challenger
AS contestant_odds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN data_bets.horse = data_events.challenger THEN data_bets.amount ELSE 0 END)  /
        SUM(CASE WHEN data_bets.horse = data_events.contestant THEN data_bets.amount END) 
       ) as bet_odds
```

Comment: I'm now using our conditional aggregate statement to fetch up/down votes from the data_votes table, but I'm having some trouble. Mind if I update this question with the new query?

Comment: @DanL . . .  You should ask another question.